# Select an object based on random number in C#

Tags: c#, random

I want to randomly change the background colour of a picture box control. What I have is

```
Random Rand = new Random();
int randNum = Rand.Next(1,3);
string boxName = "pic" + randNum.ToString();
PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
picBox.Name = boxName;

picBox.BackColor = Color.White;
```

And it doesn't work. I know that `picBox.Name = boxName` doesn't actually set `picBox` to that picture box, but it's the only code that wouldn't give some intellisense error.

I have 3 picture boxes, pic1, pic2, and pic3. This is done on a button click, hence random num between 1 and 3.

I tried to apply [Choosing random places in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499046/choosing-random-places-in-c-sharp), but I couldn't get it to work, could anyone help?

Comment: You need to keep (or put) all of your `PictureBox`es in a list or array, then get a random number to select one from that list/array.

Comment: if you want to load real images then you need to create a BitMap object from the file (there is a constructor that takes a file name) and then assign that image to the .BackgroundImage of the PictureBox object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array of `PictureBox`:

```
var boxes = new [] { pic1, pic2, pic3 };
```

and use it when selecting random one:

```
var picBox = boxes[Rand.Next(0, 3)];
```

*Note: You have to draw from 0 (included) to 3 (excluded), because arrays are indexed from 0.*

Than you'll have a random `PictureBox` assigned to your `picBox` variable, so you can change the background:

```
picBox.BackColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: A better practice would be `boxes[Rand.Next(0, boxes.Length)]` in case  the number of picture boxes changes in future

Comment: @codemonkeh You will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` there I'm afraid. `boxes[Rand.Next(0, boxes.Length-1)]` would work better ;)

Comment: @Gusdor You're wrong. `Random.Next` takes the second parameter as *exclusive*.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek so it does. School day!

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply store the colours in an array and change the background colour at random? No need to recreate a picture box.

```
Color[] colours = new Color[] { Color.White, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Red }; //etc
Random Rand = new Random();
int randNum = Rand.Next(0, colours.Length);
```

And then to assign the colour:

```
picBox.BackColor = colours[randNum];
```

Comment: This actually answers the question!

Comment: I was confused for a minute, then realized I wasn't clear in my question... I want the colour predefined, and the randomization being on the picture boxes, i.e. out of the 3 picboxes, a random one has the colour change.

Comment: @Edper as per MSDN "A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to zero, and less than maxValue" Where maxValue in this case is the Length.

Comment: @Daevin Ah in that case MarcinJuraszek's answer should be more accurate

Comment: @codemonkeh you're right (and my bad) I normally get confused the length/size as max value for random numbers.

Comment: @Edper Easy to do, I had to check the spec to be sure!